# How to combine YAML files in python?

Tags: python, yaml

I got some Kubernetes YAML files which I need to combine.

For that, I tried using Python.

The second file, `sample.yaml`, should be merged to the first file, `source.yaml`.

The `source.yaml` file has one section `sample:`, where the complete `sample.yaml` should be added.

I tried using the below code:

```py
#pip install pyyaml
import yaml

def yaml_loader(filepath):
    #Loads a yaml file
    with open(filepath,'r')as file_descriptor:
        data = yaml.load(file_descriptor)
    return data

def yaml_dump(filepath,data):
    with open(filepath,"w") as file_descriptor:
        yaml.dump(data, file_descriptor)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path1 = "source"
    data1 = yaml_loader(file_path1)
    file_path2 = "sample.yaml"

    with open(file_path2, 'r') as file2:
        sample_yaml = file2.read()
    data1['data']['sample'] = sample_yml
    yaml_dump("temp.yml", data1)
```

This is creating a new file `temp.yml` but instead of line breaks, it is saving `\n` as strings:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: You're reading the second file as string/bytes. Should you also be using `yaml_loader()` on the second file to get another dictionary, then merge the dictionary?

Comment: I tried that but it is tampering the sections with same name.Is there any wayt to dump the second yaml as is and just keeping the line gaps instead of \n?

Comment: What you're doing is including the second YAML as a single string. You get `\n` and surrounding double quotes because you assign a single string value to `sample`. If you want to include the data structure described in the second file's YAML, you *have* to load it as YAML so that Python understands the structure.

Comment: To get any help you're going to have to add representative samples of both your yaml files.

Comment: Please add (short) samples of you input files to your question so it's a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Your original YAML may have issues. If you use VS Code, format your YAML file. Click on the bottom of vscode(if using the same) [Spaces]

[image]

and select convert indentation to spaces

[image]

also, you can check if YAML module has any indentation property to be configured ,when loading the file